# lsof not giving o/p for bash built in read

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptor, lsof

When I do

```
find /
```

on a terminal and then do on another terminal

```
lsof -a -d 0-2 -c fin
```

I see o/p listed from execution of lsof command.

But when I do

```
echo hi ; read -t 30 hello
hi
```

on the same terminal ( as find) and do (on different terminal)

```
lsof -a -d 0-2 -c read
```

I don't get any output from lsof command

Why ? Is it because read is bash built in ? Whats happening here ?

Comment: This question technically belongs on [unix and linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it right. "read" is a shell built-in. The process name remains sh (or bash, or zsh, or whatever else is your shell of choice).

Moreover, though for some shell built-ins there are binary alternatives, there isn't one for read. Really because of its syntax, it takes in the name of a shell variable that gets assigned the result of reading from the stdin. If it was an external program, it could never set the variable in the calling shell.

Comment: from bash's 'help read':     If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable.